# failing tests in Rails Tutorial Chapter 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

```
Failures:

1) User pages signup with valid information edit with invalid information 
 Failure/Error: before { click_button "Save changes" }
 AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   The action 'update' could not be found for UsersController
 # (eval):2:in `click_button'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:105:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

 Finished in 1.13 seconds
 62 examples, 1 failure

 Failed examples:

 rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:107 # User pages signup with valid information edit with invalid information
```

I take from this that it is not seeing my update action in my users_controller.rb however it is there:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def new
   @user = User.new
 end


def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
  sign_in @user
  flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
  redirect_to @user
else
  render 'new'
 end
end


def edit
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end 
end


def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end


def update
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
  sign_in @user
  redirect_to @user
else
  render 'edit'
 end
end
```

And I somehow ended up with two edit actions but if I remove one of them I can get the tests to run at all. I think 99% of my troubles I'm having is with all the end's everywhere and inserting new actions in the wrong places. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def edit
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end 
end
```

There is a double `end` here. This ends the `class UsersController`. Just remove all these lines and you should be fine.

Comment: Thankyou that makes total sense! I just removed the repeat edit action with the double end and added an end to the end and it passed! But could I ask you to look at my user_pages_spec? I am getting failing tests on it as well and I'm hoping its something just as simple. http://pastebin.com/a7tScj4s  Thanks again!

Comment: Here is one of the failures: 1) User pages signup with valid information 
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_5::Nested_5::Nested_3:0x007f86db9bc120>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:119:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: I dont have much experience with tests. It might be a good idea to make a new question out of this. From the looks of the paste you added and the error: you dont have `user` defined in your tests. This should be a variable and my best guess is it should come out of the FactoryGirl class.

Comment: You're right I will make a new question out of this later, I was thinking two birds one stone...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You first have to match every end. You probably were removing the 2nd edit action which would've caused the UserController class to end on the first edit action because of your extra end in that action...

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end


  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem thanks. I am struggling with the ends a bit. Do you see a similar problem with my user_pages_spec by chance? http://pastebin.com/a7tScj4s

Comment: The best way to keep track of this is to actually just follow tabbing patterns and always close a block when you create it. For every do there's an end